# Number of ordered triplet solutions $(x,y,z)$

Tags: combinatorics

How many ordered triplet solutions $(x,y,z)$ does the system $x+y+z=4$, $x^2+y^2+z^2=14$ 
and $x^3+y^3+z^3=34$ have

Comment: $(x+y+z)^2=x^2+y^2+z^2+2(xy+yz+xz)$

Comment: $x^3 + y^3 + z^3 – 3xyz = (x + y + z) (x^2 + y^2 + z^2 – xy – yz – zx)$

Answer (score 3):

Since there are $3$ variables and $3$ independent equations, we have atmost $1$ solution upto ordering. Since $(3,2,-1)$ satisfy these, this is the solution and the number of ordered triplets are $3!=6$.